Promesa dentro de If
Tengo un función la cual me genera unos informes a partir de los datos de una orden/pedido.
La función dentro tiene un bucle para ver la cantidad total de impresiones que debe hacer y, después, una serie de acciones que se deben hacer.
El problema viene en que no consigo que se haga de forma lineal, es decir, primero termine una función antes de avanzar a la siguiente línea.
La función principal es:
async request(){
    for (let index = 1; index <= this.numLabels; index++) { 
      let time: number = 0;

      this.p_orderRequest.RequestId=this.generateRandomId().toString().substring(0,9);
      
      this.porderService.InsertRequest(this.p_orderRequest).subscribe(async data => {
        //Inicio intervalo con promesa para asegurar que no avance el bucle for??
          const responseRequest = await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject)=>{
            this.timerCheck = setInterval(() => {
            time = time +this.INTERVAL_DURATION_MS;
            
            if(data.type === 'success' || data.type ==='error'){              
                if(this.GetProtocol()){
                  console.log("Protocolo obtenido")
                  if(this.CheckPrintEnd()){
                    if(this.blnFinished){
                      if(this.p_orderRequest.result=="OK"){
                        this.porderService.SaveOrderRegisterControl(this.p_orderRequest).subscribe();
                        this.porderService.SaveSystemAudit(this.p_orderRequest).subscribe();
                      }             
                    this.porderService.DeleteRequest(this.p_orderRequest).subscribe();
                    }
                  }
                }
              
              time = 0;
              console.log("Ciclo pedidos terminado.")
              clearInterval(this.timerCheck)
              resolve();
            }else if(time>this.DEFAULT_TIME_OUT){
              this.p_orderRequest.result="NG:TIMEOUT=" + time
              this.UpdateRequest(this.p_orderRequest, "TIME_OUT");
              clearInterval(this.timerCheck);
              resolve();
              }else{
              console.log("Esperando respuesta del servidor")
              }
            },1000);  
          })
         this.numLabelsPrinted++
        });
     }
  }

En caso de obtener una respuesta por parte del servidor, inicio una serie de funciones ,hasta terminar el ciclo y cerrar el intervalo para poder avanzar con la siguiente impresión en caso de que la haya.
Si no obtengo respuesta en el tiempo establecido tengo configurado un time out, aunque esta parte no es la que me falla.
Sobretodo el problema lo tengo en el if(GetProtocol()) y if(CheckPrintEnd()) ya que primero me esta haciendo el console.log("Ciclo pedidos terminado.") antes de termina el GetProtocol(), y por lo tanto no consigo cerrar la impresión de la manera que lo necesito.
Esas funciones son estas:
 GetProtocol(): any{
     this.porderService.GetProtocol(this.p_orderRequest.RequestId).subscribe(data => {
      if (data.type === 'success') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }



  CheckPrintEnd():any{
    this.porderService.CheckPrintEnd(this.p_orderRequest).subscribe( data => {
     if (data.type === 'success') {
        this.p_clsRequest = JSON.parse(data.data.toString()) as POrderRequest;
        this.blnFinished = !!(this.p_orderRequest.porderValue);
        return true;
     } else {
       return false;
     }
   });
 }

He intentado crear algo parecido a la constante responseRequest que hay en el código pero no me funciona.

Esto const responseRequest = await new Promise<void>((resolve, reject)  no estará sobrando ??

Sin eso me pasaba lo mismo. Lo añadí porque sino me hacia el bucle sin haber hecho las funciones que tiene que hacer en la primera iteración, es decir, sin haber acabado la primera iteración ya empezaba la segunda.

Me queda claro cómo lo estás haciendo, pero realmente no me queda claro qué quieres hacer. ¿Quieres hacer una serie de llamadas AJAX de manera consecutiva, cada una esperando que la anterior se haya completado?

Exacto, quiero que se haga la petición y, según el valor que devuelva( true/false) continuo o no(todo esto habiendo esperado), en caso de continuar se haría lo mismo con la siguiente función.

Estás haciendo llamadas asíncronas sin más y queriendo que tu código las espere... no va a suceder. Tienes que pensar en asíncrono, y obviamente, programar en asíncrono. Quita las llamadas de esos métodos que no devuelven nada, suscríbete a ellas en tu flujo principal y mete la siguiente llamada en el .subscribe() de la anterior llamada. Es la manera mas fea de hacerlo, pero es la más sencilla, básicamente encadenas las suscripciones una dentro de otra. La mejor manera (para mi gusto), una única suscripción pipeando .maps para hacer lo que necesites en cada paso

Para utilizarlo con Promise.all te refieres?

Angular usa RxJS y, por tanto, trabaja con Observables. Mezclarlos con Promesas suele ser más confuso que útil, por lo que recomiendo no hacerlo.
Imaginemos que tienes una función que hace una llamada AJAX usando HttpClient.get (o post) y que devuelve un observable.

function getSomeData(someParam: P): Observable<SomeData> { ... }


Supongamos que quieres hacer N llamadas, donde cada una usa la respuesta de la anterior hasta que cierta respuesta nos indica que debemos parar. Podrías hacer algo como
  getAllData(someParam: P):Observable<SomeData[]> {
    //primera llamada
    return getSomeData(someParam).pipe( 
      expand((s: SomeData) => { //resultado emitido de la llamada anterior
        const nextCallParam = s.someParam
        if (someCondition(nexCallParam)) { // hay que llamar de nuevo?
           return getSomeData(nextCallParam); // sí, llamamos
        } else {
           return of(null); //no, emitimos un valor finalizador
        }
      }),
      takeWhile(data => data !== null), // paramos de observar , necesario para que reduce funcione
      reduce((acc,value)=>{return [...acc,value]},[]) //acumulamos en un array los resultados anteriores al valor null
    );

Entonces, una llamada a getAllData(...) debería devolver un array con todos los resultados en orden.
Ejemplo funcionando básico, sin AJAX: https://stackblitz.com/edit/pqsdt8?file=index.ts

En mi caso también es la mejor opción? Ya que en mi caso no necesito que solamente busco obtener primero la respuesta de la función que esta dentro del if() para seguir avanzando con la ejecución
